# String Manipulation topic message

Tags: c++, string

I am working on an assignment that requires you to subscribe to a topic, retrieve a message, then remove a character from a random spot in the string. Then republish that message to another topic. I am stuck on editing the the string and setting it to an empty space, I can not find the an ROS String solution to this problem. Any help is much appreciated.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

ros::Publisher pub;

void callback_func_name(const std_msgs::String& msg){
    int random_num = rand() % msg.data.length();

        std::string test;

        for (int x = 0; x < msg.data.length(); ++x){
            if(x == random_num){
                test.append(" ");
            }
        else{
            test.append(msg.data[x]);
        }
    }

    pub.publish(test);
    pub.publish(msg);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "hw1_changer");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    srand(time(NULL));

    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/hw1_topic", 1000, callback_func_name);
    pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::String>("/hw1_topic_changed", 10);
    ros::spin();
}
```

The first error is:

```
/home/ros-student/catkin_ws/src/my_ros_test/src/hw1_changer.cpp: In function ‘void callback_func_name(const String&)’:
/home/ros-student/catkin_ws/src/my_ros_test/src/hw1_changer.cpp:20:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::append(const value_type&)’
             test.append(msg.data[x]);
```

Comment: Unclear: why do you use C headers for C++ code ?

Comment: Your question actually has nothing to do with ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the string as `const &` which as the `const` implies can't be changed.
Change the signature to `void callback_func_name(std_msgs::String& msg){` so you take a reference to the message, which will modify the original object.

Note when taking a reference, you need to ensure that the object is still valid at the time and during the function call.
If you can't make that guarantee you'll have to adjust your code.

The line `msg[x] = " ";` should be `msg.data[x] = ' ';` because the data is contained in the data field and the subscript operator will return you a reference to the character.

The correct headers for C++ are:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
```

Answer (score 0):

The string is actually stored on data field, [see here](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html).

You should then replace the line with error with this:

```
msg.data[x] = ' ';
```

Comment: making that change gives me: " msg.data[x] = " ";
/home/ros-student/catkin_ws/src/my_ros_test/src/hw1_changer.cpp:16:25: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’"

Comment: Edited the answer!

Comment: You can also make your code much simpler using replace method: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/